# Cover the active region with a character

Tags: region, insert, self-insert-command

Called with an active region, it will replace all spaces in that region with the character corresponding to the subsequent key press. E.g., if `cover-active-region` is bound to `C-c /`, then `C-c / h` will replace all spaces (not newlines or anything) in the active region with the letter `h`.

I suppose this is a simple extension of a command that replace all characters in active region (not just whitespace).

In any case, I'm sure there is a function or idiom for this in Emacs, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You're right, @Drew. I've updated the question.

Comment: Please explain why the question has been voted down if you're going to vote down.

Comment: @Drew, I figured, otherwise you would have voted down before I made the correction. Unless you really hated my correction??

Comment: The question is clear now. Thx.

Comment: I was kidding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```el
(defun cover-active-region (beg end char)
  "Replace space with CHAR in the region."
  (interactive
   (if (use-region-p)
       (list
        (region-beginning)
        (region-end)
        (read-char))
     (user-error "No useable region")))
  (insert
   (replace-regexp-in-string
    " "
    (string char)
    (delete-and-extract-region beg end))))
```